# How To Draw UILabel On Pie Chart without Core Plot?

Tags: ios, uilabel, pie-chart

I have Drawn the pie-chart using following code:

1)created **UIView** Custom class **Piechart**

2)in **drawRect**

```
int c=[itemArray count];
[_label removeFromSuperview];
CGFloat angleArray[c];
 offset = 0.0;

int sum=0;
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetAllowsAntialiasing(context, false);
CGContextSetShouldAntialias(context, false);

for(int i=0;i<[itemArray count];i++)
{

    sum+=[[itemArray objectAtIndex:i] intValue];
}

for(int i=0;i<[itemArray count];i++)
{
    angleArray[i]=(float)(([[itemArray objectAtIndex:i] intValue])/(float)sum)*(2*3.14); // in radians
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, radius, radius);
    if(i==0)
    {
        CGContextAddArc(context, radius, radius, radius, 0,angleArray[i], 0);

    }
    else
    {
        CGContextAddArc(context, radius, radius, radius,offset,offset+angleArray[i], 0);

    }
    offset+=angleArray[i];

    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, ((UIColor *)[myColorArray objectAtIndex:i]).CGColor);
    CGContextClosePath(context); 
    CGContextFillPath(context);
}
```

3) The problem is How to draw label on each sections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (CGPoint)getApproximateMidPointForArcWithStartAngle:(CGFloat)startAngle andDegrees:(CGFloat)endAngle {

NSLog(@"start angle %f, end angle %f",startAngle,endAngle);
CGFloat midAngle = DEGREES_TO_RADIANS((startAngle + endAngle) / 2);
NSLog(@"midangle %f ",midAngle);
CGFloat x=0;
CGFloat y=0;
x= (250) + (250 * cos(midAngle));
y= (250) + (250 * sin(midAngle));

CGPoint approximateMidPointCenter = CGPointMake(((x+250)/2), ((y+250)/2));
return approximateMidPointCenter; }
```

here **approximateMidPointCenter** is **Mid-Point** of line joining **circle center** and arc's center.

label.center=approximateMidPointCenter

Answer (score 0):

You can convert polar coordinates to Cartesian coordinates by this formula

x = radius * cos(angle);

y = radius * sin(angle);

Point(x,y) can be the center of your label.

In your case angle is AVG between start and end angle. Radius is the distance between center of pie-chart and label.